# Unable to merge date (character type) and time (character type) using lubridate and keep getting N/As for the new column created

Tags: date, na, lubridate

I am trying to combine the date (mdy) and time (hms) into a new column for my data using lubridate. I want the new datetime column to be in the order of y-m-d h:m:s.

The following code I attempted to use is...

```
sa1$datetime <- ymd_hms(paste(sal$date,sal$time), format = "%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S")
```

sal1 is my data sheet which has columns date (myd | example - 7/6/23), time (hms | example - 0:00:00), and salinity values recorded every 15 minutes. However, when I run this code I get the following error...

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, datetime, value = c(NA_real_, NA_real_,  : 
  replacement has 2187 rows, data has 2186
In addition: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

While it creates the new column, only N/As show up rather than the combined values. I also omitted any N/As out of the 'sal' data so I do not believe that should be an issue.

```
sal1 <- sal[-1,]%>%
  na.omit()
```

Comment: Hi siyjin22! Can you include some of your data? Use dput please :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your actual data is not in year month day format, but day month year, or perhaps month day year format. So instead of `ymd_hms()`, you need to use either `dmy_hms()` or `mdy_hms()`:

```r
# create an example dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  date = c("7/6/23", "6/9/69"),
  time = c("0:00:00", "4:20:00"))

dmy_hms(paste(df$date,df$time)) # [1] "2023-06-07 00:00:00 UTC" "1969-09-06 04:20:00 UTC"
```

To convert the dates to be strings of the format y-m-d h:m:s, you only need to use `as.character()`, as that is the default format :-)